# How to install usb wifi on rpi

Tags: raspbian, usb, wifi, dhcp, wpa

[image]

I have been trying to install this antenna on the pi but when I failed, I tried modifying the `/etc/network/interfaces` file via `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` to

```
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid "MY ssid"
wpa-psk "MY password"
```

but there is no connection. I need to install this antenna to send files from the pi to a laptop wirelessly using the laptop's IP.

Any idea how to firstly configure this usb antenna and then how to send to a device?

I am using a Raspberry Pi model B running raspbian on it.

Comment: please edit your question and post the output of "lsusb" command so we can understand what device you're using. Maybe your distro didn't have your device's driver and it may not recognized yet. Without recognize it your config file will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing and using wicd:

```
sudo apt-get install wicd-curses
```

Now, you are ready to start:

```
sudo wicd-curses
```

You will get a list of wireless networks, found by RPi, and your wired network.

[image: Using wicd with Raspberry Pi]

Then, you can select your wifi network. Just highlight it with arrow keys and press right arrow key to edit its properties.

When you’re done, just press F10 to save it.
It should connect!

Comment: everytime I do so it terminated the ssh session without connecting. Is there a reason or something I am doing wrong? Ido choose my network and type the key then ok and finally C to connect.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would type the command

```
lsusb
```

And check the chipset of the WiFi dongle. It would save a lot of time in searching for it online.

I think in order to achieve your goal setting raspberry pi as an access point would do, I'm not really an expert but you can try doing that. I've set mine using the this [link](http://blog.sip2serve.com/post/48899893167/rtl8188-access-point-install-script)
But notice that my wifi dongle chip is rtl8188cus. This may differ from yours.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying to setup wifi using the GUI. If you are using a monitor launch the GUI by typing startx into the command line. If you are using shh install tightvncserver and connect with a vnc client. The wifi config tool is on the desktop, it is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: what if he/she didn't install X Server? Also he/she didn't mentioned what distribution he/she use.

Comment: I didnt install X server and I am usng raspbian